# Unmount gvfs samba share with open file

Tags: mount, samba, gvfs, kill, lsof

I have a samba share mounted. I'm trying to unmount it on the commandline.

```
$ gvfs-mount -u smb://server/root/
Error unmounting mount: Filesystem is busy
```

I ran `lsof` to find open files, but I can't figure out what PID I need to kill. It doesn't say `smb://server/root/my-open-file`. How do I find out which PID to kill?

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -i -a username | grep ^gvfs
```

-i
only list network connections (see manpage for more options)

-a username
only list files opened by a specific user

grep ^gvfs
only list files opened by gvfs